# Occasional "echoed" usernames in Firefox

Tags: bug, user-interface

I noticed about a month ago that quite often in the latest version of Firefox (but not in Chrome) under Windows 11 usernames become distorted like this

[image]

Does anybody else see this or it is just me?

**Later** - following suggestions in comments, I looked into that user's page and there I see this:

[image]

Comment: Hmm Dmitri Piontkovski's profile image shows up as text, for me on Firefox on Android,  and in the image you give it's a cropped version of this you are seeing.

Comment: It looks like the user's profile picture is not being loaded, so you're instead setting the alt text for the image — or, a cropped portion of it, since the alt text is probably "*username*'s profile picture". Perhaps you're using an ad blocker, or perhaps Firefox is aggressively filtering out certain images?

Comment: The user's profile picture is being pulled in from Facebook (https://graph.facebook.com/1852493471481940/picture?type=large), so it could be that Firefox is not liking the 3rd party image link?

Comment: @TheAmplitwist I am indeed using ABP but right now I switched it off completely and reloaded the page, with no avail. How to check Firefox about image filtering I don't know.

Comment: Aha there is indeed evidence about image filtering, let me add this to the question

Comment: A related question on Meta SE: [Why is there "\[username name\]s' user avatar" on this user's avatar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386934)

Answer (score 3):

Suggestions in the comments by David Roberts and The Amplitwist turned out to be correct.
I switched out enhanced tracking protection, and that thing got replaced with a picture of the user.
Still I am not removing the bug tag since when the protection is on, something less messy should appear I believe, no?

Besides, it does not look normal that in order for the page to load properly I should allow facebook to track my *personal* actions

Comment: A related feature request on Meta SE: [Off-site avatar images are a privacy risk](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328966). Quoting from the post ([revision 7](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/328966/7)), "The Facebook avatars are blocked by the default setting of the Firefox tracking protection, so anyone using Firefox with this enabled will see a slightly broken SE site. [Firefox is also enabling tracking protection by default now](https://blog.mozilla.org/blog/2019/06/04/firefox-now-available-with-enhanced-tracking-protection-by-default), so this will affect a lot more people soon."